# Problemas al visualizar un listview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-asynctask

Cordial Saludo,

Desarrollé un APP perfectamente en Android Studio, lo probé en mi teléfono y funcionó de maravilla, pero cuando lo instalo en una tablet logro iniciar sesion pero luego del inicio de sesión debería aparecer un Listview, el cual no aparece y se detiene tratando de mostrar el Listview.

Dato: El teléfono funciona con la Android 8.0 y la Tablet con la Android 6.0, la API mínima para el funcionamiento es la 5.0 el APP ha funcionado en teléfonos con la 6.0

El Logcat de cada dispositivo arroja diferentes resultados.

Logcat del celular que anda bien el APP:

```
06-04 10:24:01.122 10270-10270/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/INFO:: ID PUESTO: 1 
06-04 10:24:01.398 10270-10301/com.example.clon.appcontroles I/System.out:
URL sentidos: http://BERLINUXERP:8000/BERLINUXERP/model/sentido.php?dato=getsentidosxcontrol&idpuesto=1
06-04 10:24:01.398 10270-10301/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Lectura de 
CADENA: Iniciar leyendo antes del OpenHttpConnection 
06-04 10:24:01.484 10270-10275/com.example.clon.appcontroles I/zygote: 
compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init
(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
06-04 10:24:01.509 10270-10301/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Lectura de         
CADENA: despues del OpenHttpConnection antes del InputStreamReader
06-04 10:24:01.510 10270-10301/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Lectura de 
CADENA: antes del InputStreamReader antes del while dentro del while Leyendo 
el inputBuffer 
06-04 10:24:01.511 10270-10301/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Lectura de 
CADENA: readString =  [{"s_id":1,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - 
CIENAGA","s_tipo_servicio":"BASICO"},{"s_id":2,"s_nombre":"CIENAGA - SANTA 
MARTA","s_tipo_servicio":"BASICO"},{"s_id":3,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - 
FUNDACION","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":4,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA 
- VALLEDUPAR","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":5,"s_nombre":"SANTA 
MARTA - SANTA ANA","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"}, 
{"s_id":6,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - EL 
BANCO","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":7,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - 
PIVIJAY","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":8,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - 
ALGARROBO","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":9,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA 
- BARRANQUILLA","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"}]
CADENA =  [{"s_id":1,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - 
CIENAGA","s_tipo_servicio":"BASICO"},{"s_id":2,"s_nombre":"CIENAGA - SANTA 
MARTA","s_tipo_servicio":"BASICO"},{"s_id":3,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - 
FUNDACION","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":4,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA 
- VALLEDUPAR","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":5,"s_nombre":"SANTA 
MARTA - SANTA ANA","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"}, 
{"s_id":6,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - EL 
BANCO","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":7,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - 
PIVIJAY","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":8,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - 
ALGARROBO","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":9,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA 
- BARRANQUILLA","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"}] despues del while
06-04 10:24:01.521 10270-10301/com.example.clon.appcontroles I/System.out: 
llamando a... URL vehiculos: 
http://BERLINUXERP:8000/BERLINUXERP/model/vehiculo.php?dato=getvehiculos
06-04 10:24:01.648 10270-10295/com.example.clon.appcontroles 
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x97d15580 (RippleDrawable) with 
handle 0xa93036f0
06-04 10:24:01.722 10270-10301/com.example.clon.appcontroles I/System.out: 
Respuesta de.. URL vehiculos: 
http://BERLINUXERP:8000/BERLINUXERP/model/vehiculo.php?dato=getvehiculos
06-04 10:24:01.787 10270-10301/com.example.clon.appcontroles I/System.out: 
URL Conductores: http://BERLINUXERP:8000/BERLINUXERP/model/conductor.php? 
dato=getconductores
```

Logcat de la Tablet donde no se puede visualizar el listView:

```
06-04 10:18:48.586 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/INFO:: ID
PUESTO: 1
06-04 10:18:48.605 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles 
D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{b14106f 
token=android.os.BinderProxy@5379a05 
{com.example.clon.appcontroles/com.example.clon.appcontroles.LoginActivity}}
06-04 10:18:48.612 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles 
D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / 
android.os.BinderProxy@5379a05
06-04 10:18:48.621 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles 
V/ActivityThread: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{71bdf35 
token=android.os.BinderProxy@cde5fca 
{com.example.clon.appcontroles/com.example.clon.appcontroles.RutasActivity}} 
startsNotResumed=false
06-04 10:18:48.638 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles 
V/ActivityThread:ActivityRecord{71bdf35token=android.os.BinderProxy@cde5fca


{com.example.clon.appcontroles/com.example.clon.appcontroles.RutasActivity}}: 
app=android.app.Application@b7b448b, appName=com.example.clon.appcontroles, 
pkg=com.example.clon.appcontroles, comp=
{com.example.clon.appcontroles/com.example.clon.appcontroles.RutasActivity}, 
dir=/data/app/com.example.clon.appcontroles-1/base.apk
06-04 10:18:48.644 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles 
E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
06-04 10:18:48.757 13346-13390/com.example.clon.appcontroles I/System.out: 
URL sentidos: http://BERLINUXERP:8000/BERLINUXERP/model/sentido.php?

dato=getsentidosxcontrol&idpuesto=1
06-04 10:18:48.757 13346-13390/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Lectura de CADENA: Iniciar leyendo
    antes del OpenHttpConnection

06-04 10:18:48.758 13346-13390/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=BERLINUXERP; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
06-04 10:18:48.758 13346-13390/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
06-04 10:18:48.759 13346-13390/com.example.clon.appcontroles I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:0
06-04 10:18:48.760 13346-13390/com.example.clon.appcontroles I/System.out: [CDS]SO_SND_TIMEOUT:0
[OkHttp] sendRequest>>
[OkHttp] sendRequest<<
06-04 10:18:48.784 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0xaaeb7d00)
06-04 10:18:48.785 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xaf9c2000 initialize window=0xaaeb7d08, title=com.example.clon.appcontroles/com.example.clon.appcontroles.RutasActivity
06-04 10:18:48.785 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0xaaeb7d00,api=1)

06-04 10:18:48.785 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
06-04 10:18:48.786 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0xaaeb7d00,bufferCount=4)
06-04 10:18:48.798 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xabb150d0) (w:600 h:1024 s:608 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
06-04 10:18:48.833 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 0, 1024, 511
06-04 10:18:48.846 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 69, 1024, 233
06-04 10:18:48.862 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xabb1a2a0) (w:543 h:226 s:544 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
06-04 10:18:48.867 13346-13390/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Lectura de CADENA: despues del OpenHttpConnection
    antes del InputStreamReader
    antes del InputStreamReader
    antes del while
    dentro del while
    Leyendo el inputBuffer 
06-04 10:18:48.868 13346-13390/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Lectura de CADENA: readString =  [{"s_id":1,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - CIENAGA","s_tipo_servicio":"BASICO"},{"s_id":2,"s_nombre":"CIENAGA - SANTA MARTA","s_tipo_servicio":"BASICO"},{"s_id":3,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - FUNDACION","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":4,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - VALLEDUPAR","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":5,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - SANTA ANA","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":6,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - EL BANCO","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":7,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - PIVIJAY","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":8,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - ALGARROBO","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":9,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - BARRANQUILLA","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"}]
    CADENA =  [{"s_id":1,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - CIENAGA","s_tipo_servicio":"BASICO"},{"s_id":2,"s_nombre":"CIENAGA - SANTA MARTA","s_tipo_servicio":"BASICO"},{"s_id":3,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - FUNDACION","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":4,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - VALLEDUPAR","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":5,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - SANTA ANA","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":6,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - EL BANCO","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":7,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - PIVIJAY","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":8,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - ALGARROBO","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"},{"s_id":9,"s_nombre":"SANTA MARTA - BARRANQUILLA","s_tipo_servicio":"BERLINAVE"}]
    despues del while
06-04 10:18:48.881 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xabb1a3f0) (w:600 h:1024 s:608 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
06-04 10:18:48.900 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 142, 1024, 182
06-04 10:18:48.902 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0xaaeb6f00,api=1)
06-04 10:18:48.902 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xabb13690) (w:543 h:226 s:544 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
06-04 10:18:48.903 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xabb1a2a0) (w:543 h:226 s:544 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
06-04 10:18:48.904 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0xaaeb6f00,api=1)
06-04 10:18:48.911 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{402be64 V.E...... R......D 0,0-479,162}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@aac0745
06-04 10:18:48.919 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0xaaeb3e00,api=1)
06-04 10:18:48.919 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xaab5eb30) (w:600 h:1024 s:608 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
06-04 10:18:48.920 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xaab5eac0) (w:600 h:1024 s:608 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
06-04 10:18:48.921 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xaab5eba0) (w:600 h:1024 s:608 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
06-04 10:18:48.922 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0xaaeb3e00,api=1)
06-04 10:18:48.923 13346-13388/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xafa4d480 (RippleDrawable @3a508f3) with handle 0xb47d7f50
06-04 10:18:48.937 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=272 first=true flags=#81810100
    START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{d6aae96 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-600,1024} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@29762c7 controlFlags=#104
06-04 10:18:49.236 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5d79e67 V.E...... R......D 0,0-600,1024}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@aac0745
06-04 10:18:49.237 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/ActivityThread: ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@5379a05
06-04 10:19:48.375 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{d6aae96 V.E...... R....... 0,0-600,1024} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@777e0f4 controlFlags=#100
06-04 10:19:48.442 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{71bdf35 token=android.os.BinderProxy@cde5fca {com.example.clon.appcontroles/com.example.clon.appcontroles.RutasActivity}}
06-04 10:19:48.490 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@cde5fca
06-04 10:19:48.499 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles V/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{71bdf35 token=android.os.BinderProxy@cde5fca {com.example.clon.appcontroles/com.example.clon.appcontroles.RutasActivity}}: show=true win=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow@54d501d
06-04 10:19:48.499 13346-13346/com.example.clon.appcontroles D/ActivityThread: ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_SHOW handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@cde5fca
```

Comment: Busca en el LogCat un mensaje que inicie con "Caused by" con esto ubicaras el problema real.

Comment: Encontré que el problema son los ProgressDialog, cuando los quito a todos la aplicación funciona bien. Los estoy trabajando de esta manera, no se si estoy haciendo algo mal:

private ProgressDialog mProgressBar;

mProgressBar = new ProgressDialog(MisControlesActivity.this);
mProgressBar.setCancelable(false);
mProgressBar.setTitle("Espere...");
mProgressBar.setMessage("Consultando Información");
mProgressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
mProgressBar.show();

Cuando coloco los ProgressDialog los ListView no funcionan